# XMLException when processing RSS

Tags: c#, xml, rss, argotic

I've been trying to process RSS feeds using Argotic for my newsreader application. For most of them it works fine, but on some feed ([like this](http://www.goal.com/en/feeds/news?fmt=rss&ICID=HP)) it breaks with the following:

> Additional information: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this
>   XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property
>   on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into
>   XmlReader.Create method.

The error was straightforward, I passed an `XMLReaderSettings` object with `DtdProcessing` enabled. But then the following appeared:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll Additional information: The ';' character, hexadecimal
>   value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name. Line 9, position 366.

The code I am using:

```
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(this.url, settings);
    RssFeed feed = new RssFeed();
    feed.Load(reader);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The link you provided successfully validates. Please post the link of the feed which generated the exact exception message that you posted, if it wasn't this link.

Comment: This is the strange part, the feed I provided is valid, but this is the one causing the error.

Comment: Can you run your code again please? Maybe the feed has been updated and the illegal part has disappeared?

Comment: You are right, this error is disappeared but another is showing up when using Argotic, I'll update my question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ignoring the `DtdProcessing` solved my problem.

```
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that the RSS feed is illegal - specifically, that a name contains the `;` character. The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) appears to prohibit this:

> Document authors are encouraged to use names which are meaningful
>   words or combinations of words in natural languages, and to avoid
>   symbolic or white space characters in names. Note that COLON,
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and MIDDLE
>   DOT are explicitly permitted.
>
> The ASCII symbols and punctuation marks, along with a fairly large
>   group of Unicode symbol characters, are excluded from names

Since other RSS readers also complained the feed was likely invalid. At the time of writing however, the W3C validator [shows it to be valid](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goal.com%2Fen%2Ffeeds%2Fnews%3Ffmt%3Drss%26ICID%3DHP)!

According to the MSDN documentation for [XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel(v=vs.110).aspx), this issue will cause an exception whatever your `ConformanceLevel`, but you might find another setting in [XmlReaderSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) which can turn the behaviour off (supply the settings to [XmlReader.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx)). Otherwise, if the feed can't be fixed, you'll have to perform some pre-processing on it.

Comment: Note this was an answer to the question as originally posed.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea for my current problem? I can't get anywhere with it.